# installing APK via ADB hangs the emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, adb

I am trying to install an apk in the emulator using following command:

```
adb install xyz.apk
```

But it takes forever and then hangs the emulator.

I don't know what to do cause I have tried the following

1. **Start the emulator with big partition size**
   `emulator @test -no-boot-anim -partition-size 256`
   *(same problem)*
2. **Install in a new emulator**
   same result.

Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: no error just a black screen in the emulator.

Comment: increase internal storage of your emulator and try again. try to install apk after emulator working properly.

Comment: @Andrain isn't 200MB enough? I try to install the APK when home is up and running.

Comment: i had same problem last week but i increased it to 512 and problem has  been solved.

Comment: try it and tell me the result..! @SMR

Comment: @Andrain I have executed the command after increasing the internal storage size. lets see how long.... OK!! that worked. thanks!!  it took `393.287s`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just increase internal storage of your emulator and try again. try to install apk after emulator working properly. I had same problem last week but i increased it to 512 and problem has been solved.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

Just increase the emulator internal storage by go to Android Virtual Device Manager-->select emulator-->edit--> Internal Storage-->increase size to >512-->OK and try..

Comment: yes @Andrain already raised that issue. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SMR But I explained clearly with step by step before he answered. May it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This install hang can also happen if you build the APK for ARMv7 only and then try to install it on the emulator because the emulator requires an x86 image.